# псевдоклассы кнопок в bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap

Есть блок кнопок, использую в проекте bootstrap. Цвет кнопок решил подстроить под себя, но стандартный синий цвет все равно проскакивает при клике. Использовал псевдокласс :active, но без результатов, вот пример:

```
.commonButton:active {
    background: #978e83;
    color: white;
    z-index:0;
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/EiZHZXo1hCFOkolgjNQ4?p=preview

подскажите как убрать эту мелькающую синеву?

Comment: .commonButton:focus{css}

Comment: к сожалению нет, откорректировал plnkr - синий цвет остался

Comment: стили bootstrapа перебивают ваши стили, т.к имеют больший вес https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/c9m0vveo/

Comment: точно, спасибо за совет, все вышло

Comment: @soledar10 Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Этот эффект с синим цветом дает псевдокласс [:focus](http://htmlbook.ru/css/focus)
2. Стили bootstrapа перебивают ваши стили, т.к имеют больший вес

Answer (score 0):

Главное — переназначить главенство своего правила через **!important**.

В вашем случае получается так:

```
.commonButton:active, .commonButton:focus,{
    background: #978e83!important;
    color: white;
    z-index:0;
}
```